# How to post the tweet in twitter from our application?

Tags: iphone, twitter

I am developing one application. In that I want to post a tweet on twitter.

I am already posting a tweet by using twitter agent, but that tweet was not updated.

Please guide me how to post the tweet from our application.

Comment: Have a look at ShareKit http://getsharekit.com/ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to use MGTwitterEngine or SAOauthTwitterengine. Get sample code [here](http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) and got to work.

[self.twitterEngine sendUpdate:yourtexttopost];

Answer (score 1):

Use Twitter API and some wrappers for iOS

[MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/jdg/MGTwitterEngine-OAuth)

[Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage)

Answer (score 0):

Wait for iOS 5.0 and use the built in twitter support.

*(twitter support isn't under NDA it was in the keynote)*